# Is there way to prove a problem is in NP without a verifier?

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory

There is a theorem that states that if A is polynomially reducible to B and B is in P, then A will be in P.

Now, would that hold for NP problems?

Simply, since coming out with verifiers all the time might be a longer/trickier task if there is a actually an easier way to to prove something is in NP.

Comment: Have you tried *proving* this? Proof is the way we verify claims in mathematics.